# conditional statement with radio button value

Tags: conditionals, ee3

I'm not sure if this is an EE bug or if I'm doing something wrong.  I'm looping through my "tournaments" channel entries and for each entry I'm looping through a "teams" channel that has a relationship to the tournaments channel.  Looping is fine with {parents}.

I'm trying to test a radio button field value and create a dropdown based off that.

I can spit out the value and it works fine and spits out the correct value if I just use {parents:team_confirmed:value}. However my {if} doesn't seem to work properly.

Here's my code in a nutshell:

```
{parents field="tournaments_attending"}

       other stuff

       <select name="confirmed">
           {if parents:team_confirmed:value == 1}
               <option value="Yes" selected>Yes</option>
               <option value="No">No</option>
           {if:else}
               <option value="No" selected>No</option>
               <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
           {/if}
       </select>

{/parents}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why for anyone curious.  It wanted curly brackets inside the {if}.

```
{if {parents:team_confirmed:value} == 1}
```